# stage is not added to the endpoint when deploy with sls deploy --stage dev

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am using serverless framework. I have set the stage as the dev and deploying using sls deploy --stage dev command. The dev stage is not added to the end point. The endpoints are not like the one given below:

```
https://****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/users
```

One of my lambda functions needs an endpoint to submit a post request to a third-party API to post back the result.  I need to be sure that the endpoint is rightly sent from the production/dev stage.

```
postback_url = `https://${process.env.RestApiId}.execute-api.${
            process.env.REGION
        }.amazonaws.com/${process.env.stage}/dfs-pingback?id=$id&tag=$tag`;
```

As you can see the above postback url is wrong if I do not get the stage (process.env.stage)  added to the endpoint.

serverless.yml

```
service: lytoolsApi
frameworkVersion: '2 || 3'
configValidationMode: error
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  stage: dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverless Framework does things a bit differently and instead of using stages of APIGW, it creates a totally new APIGW for each stage, that's why you don't see the prefix in your path with the stage name, but if you observe the url, you'll see that the base url will be different across stages. That's how you can differentiate between them.